# Como alterar apenas uma cor no Pillow (Python)

Tags: python, image

No meu site, consegui fazer com que ao por `?size=200` em um link de imagem, redimensionar a imagem para o width 200, mantendo aspecto, quero fazer o mesmo, só que com `?fill=ff00ff` que alteraria toda cor branca para rosa, não sei como começar... (Já converti hex para rgb)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Me baseando [nesta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3752476/python-pil-replace-a-single-rgba-color?answertab=votes#tab-top) do SO em inglês, basicamente é preciso abrir a imagem, passar para um `numpy.array`, pegar os canais RGB, definir uma condição (ex: onde a cor é branca) e substituir os valores do array para a cor desejada onde a condição (cor ser branca) é satisfeita.

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

cor_rosa_magenta = (255, 0, 144)

im = Image.open('minha_imagem.png').convert('RGB')

# Pega a imagem como um numpy.array com formato altura x largura x num_canais
data = np.array(im)

#>>> print(data.shape)
#    (200, 200, 3)

# Pego cada canal como um array separado para facilitar reconhecer o branco
vermelho, verde, azul = data.T

# Defino a condição (ser branco)
condicao = (vermelho == 255) & (verde == 255) & (azul == 255)
# Substitui a cor branca pela cor desejada
data[condicao.T] = cor_rosa_magenta

# Volto o array para uma imagem do PIL
im2 = Image.fromarray(data)
```

Porém dizer que a cor branca é exatamente `(255, 255, 255)` é um pouco utópico. Acho que o resultado será melhor se utilizar a condição de "quase branco":

```
condicao = (vermelho >= 225) & (verde >= 225) & (azul >= 225)
```

Comment: Vou tentar, mas no caso seria branco mesmo, pq eu que fiz as imagens, mas vou por essa condicao

Comment: Eu já tinha visto essa mas tava dando erro de "bool", mas funcionou vlw

Comment: Parou de funcionar, ta dando too many values to unpack

Comment: Se funcionou para uma imagem, mas para outra não, sugiro fazer uma outra pergunta apontando o código utilizado, o caso que funcionou, o caso que não funcionou, o erro encontrado, a linha em que ele ocorre e a forma do array `data` (`data.shape`). Apenas com a mensagem de erro "too many values to unpack" fica difícil identificar o problema.